# React.lazy error Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to Lazy Load the App component. I've read the React doc samples and have come up with the solution below. However, I get a `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` and I'm not sure why. I've also tried doing `import('').default`.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// import { App } from './components/navigation';
// import Login from './components/login/LoginContainer';
import PrivateRoute from './components/privateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

const Login = lazy(() => import('./components/login/LoginContainer'));
const App = lazy(() => import('./components/navigation/AppContainer'));

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route name="login" exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route name="loginWithTripId" exact path="/login/:tripid" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/trips/:tripid" component={App} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/trips/dashboard" component={App} />
          <Route render={() => <Redirect to={'/login'} />} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Main);
```

For some reason React.lazy is `undefined` if I console.log it... I've tried removing node_modules and doing `npm install` again with no success

Comment: `console.log(lazy);` is that working?

Comment: Oh Interesting... lazy is undefined?

Comment: React version used?

Comment: React 16.6 - just upgraded. Im going to try to delete node_modules and do `npm install` again EDIT: It still console.log as `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to get it fixed by turning off my development server and restarting using npm start.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: You should turn off your node dev server and restart. It should fix the issue.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Unfortunately restarting didn't work but thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Restarting didn't work for me either. Getting Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.  Above Fabio Ansaldi solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In a development server, using for example webpack-dev-server, you have to use:

`const Login = lazy(() => import('./components/navigation/LoginContainer'));
...
<Route name="login" exact path="/login" component={props => <Login {...props} />} />
...`

and it will works also in a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Check you React Version, lazy was introduced in 16.6

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html